# MySQL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE field="some text" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I am trying to INNER JOIN two tables on a text field, but I can't get it to work.
I've backtracked to see if I can identify where my query is falling down.
I've simplified my query to use only one table, to see if I can select data from it based on a text string.
I can't make it work.
I feel like an *idiot*.
This is so basic, why isn't it doing it?

```
select * from `my-table`
where myKey = "some-text-data-that-i-copied-from-the-data-in-the-table";
```

Returns no rows.
"some-text-data-that-i-copied-from-the-data-in-the-table" is in field myKey. I can see it. It's in the table!!!

[if it makes any difference I am most familiar with using an Access front-end and I am porting my "skills" to MySQL because MySQL is just better really.. this seems like the most run of the mill SELECT statement ever and yet it doesn't do anything!]

EDIT:

IMSoP does this help any...

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey = 'KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1';
```

EDIT 2:

Diego Marinelli - thanks - this returns data

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey like '%KS2%';
```

EDIT 3:

This works...

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey like '%KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1%';
```

EDIT 4:

But this still doesn't...

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey = 'KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1';
```

*puzzled*

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mymathssowlink` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ObjectiveID` varchar(13),
  `MyMathsResourceKey` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idnew_table_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

HOW IT GOT FIXED:

okay very weird but I have fixed the simplified problem now! I remember from my Access days that trailing spaces are the bane of matches and it seems the MySQL is a bit fiddly in this regard to. There was no problem with the data as such but the field MyMathsResourceKey was the last bit of data on each line and so not terminated with a comma. Some lines didn't have any data in that column and so were terminated with a comma rather than the MyMathsResourceKey data. I fixed it by adding a third column to my csv into which i uniformly stuck the string "PLACEHOLDER". I matched this to a column called `placeholder` in the table receiving the data. Now that the active (2nd column) is always terminated with a comma all the data seems to work. I can't help thinking that this is a bit odd and that MySQL data imports really don't want to be behaving like this... now to try an make my JOIN work, which how this all started!

Thanks to all, especially Rahul for the help.

... and the JOIN Works now...

Comment: You're doing something else wrong.  Be assured that MySQL works fine and can SELECT from dusk til dawn if told correctly.  You'll make more progress if you assume that you're wrong first, last, and always.  Show the CREATE TABLE SQL and the details of your JOIN.

Comment: Try this :
select * from `my-table`
where myKey = "%some-text%";

Comment: Is that the actual text that you're searching for ? If not you need to show the exact string as characters in that string may break the query

Comment: CREATE TABLE `my-table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myOtherKey` varchar(13),
  `myKey` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idnew_table_UNIQUE` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible for us to do anything other than guess what you're doing wrong, because you've anonymized your example to the extent that crucial details are probably hidden from us. If you can't share your real data, perhaps you could create a self-contained example that exhibits the problem; trying to do so may even make you realise what's going wrong. There's a tool at http:// sqlfiddle.com that lets you create share live demos of data and queries.

Comment: When you do add details, please do so by clicking edit under the question, as comments have very limited formatting, and things get very confusing if you try to squeeze everything into them.

Comment: IMSoP does this help any...select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey = 'KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1';

Comment: This is working for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b11eb/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by all the edits in your post and comments; what I feel is, there is extra space present in your column value and so you are not getting the data (since it's not matching the exact string).

So either try like

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where MyMathsResourceKey 
like '%KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1%';
```

(OR)

Use a `REPLACE()` function to remove all spaces in the field value

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where REPLACE(MyMathsResourceKey, ' ', '') 
= 'KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1';
```

You can as well use `TRIM()` function if you can guarantee that the spaces are present only in left/right extreme of the string.

```
select * from mymathssowlink
where TRIM(MyMathsResourceKey) 
= 'KS2-Number-Counting and Place Value-NC3-Negative Numbers 1';
```

Comment: Rahul I think you are close to nailing it there. If I pick up the data from the table in Workbench and copy it into the "clause" ... it doesn't work. If I copy the data in the "clause" BACK INTO the table then it does work! I pulled my data in from Excel having converted to .csv. Is it possible that there is *some rubbish* in the text field? If so can I fix the data in MySQL by stripping spaces or do I need to reimport? Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: @JimmyWeb, Yes I am pretty sure about that; the error is cause you have copy/pasted from csv directly. this kind of issue raises only when there is extra space/hidden character/junk character. Just sanitate the column value and all will be cool.

Comment: Rahul - I've tried to UPDATE the whole set of data with:    update mymathssowlink SET MyMathsResourceKey = TRIM(MyMathsResourceKey);     it hasn't changed anything. I don't understand what your REPLACE function above is doing... what am I replacing with what? ' ' with '' looks like it will strip out all of the spaces in the string.. which I don't really want to do!

Comment: @JimmyWeb, I used replace considering extra spaces but you can as well use `TRIM()` function to trim leading/trailing spaces before comparison (see edited answer). Again, I believe you did a import data from csv to MySQL table ... suggesting you to verify those data once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Select * from table;` and if that works then try `select * from table where key like '%some_text%'`
It could not be a problem with the sintax but with the query itself.